# rviz - video recording

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Is it possible to make a video recording from rviz displays?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66988/rviz---video-recording/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible. Just use a screen capture utility. For Ubuntu, you can use something like [Kazam](http://www.twm-kd.com/category/linux/kazam/).

```
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Run it, then select the part of the window you wish to record.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just for reference, here's some other desktop video recording options in ubuntu I use to record graphical stuff (e.g. rviz, gazebo, etc):

- [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php), and @scpeters has a script that lets you click on a window to record it:

  ```
  alias recordmywindow='window_id=`xwininfo | grep "Window id" | sed -e "s@.*Window id: \([0-9a-fA-Fx]*\).*@\1@"`; recordmydesktop --workdir /home/hsu/videos --no-sound --windowid $window_id'
  ```
- [vlc screen://](http://superuser.com/questions/782959/how-to-record-desktop-in-vlc-second-screen) and piping `--sout` to a file or some other media.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2015-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/lucasw/screen_grab captures a parameter defined area of the screen and publishes it as a ros image.  From there the image can be recorded to a bag and then exported to a video http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data .

The other approach is publishing an image from a camera within rviz (if it isn't necessary to capture the user interface, or annoying to adjust the window position and screen capture settings to match each other).  There isn't a good way to do that yet but there are some possibilities that might not take too much development http://answers.ros.org/question/142351/publishing-virtual-camera-images-from-rviz/

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [jsk_rviz_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/jsk_rviz_plugins?distro=indigo) package that is available via apt in some ROS distros, there's [VideoCapture](http://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/video_capture.html) plugin.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2019-04-09**:
I only get a huge video that shows only green pixels along with some noise.

**Comment by [robbyHuelsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50332/robbyhuelsi/) on 2019-12-17**:
VLC can fix that.